# A proof that air resistance isn't conservative

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, drag, dissipation

I want to show that a force depending on the velocity $\dot{\underline{r}}$, where $\underline{r}$ is the position vector of a particle, cannot be conservative since there is energy dissipation. Here, I'm considering the usual air resistance force
$$
\underline{F}=-k \dot{\underline{r}}
$$
where $k>0$ is a constant. Could you please check if my proof is correct?

First, from Newton's second law, we know that
$$
\underline{F}=m\ddot{\underline{r}}.
$$
Dotting this equation with $\dot{\underline{r}}$ leads to
$$
m\ddot{\underline{r}}\cdot \dot{\underline{r}}=\underline{F}\cdot \dot{\underline{r}}=-k\dot{\underline{r}}\cdot \dot{\underline{r}}.
$$
Hence, we get
$$
m\ddot{\underline{r}}\cdot \dot{\underline{r}}+ k\dot{\underline{r}}\cdot \dot{\underline{r}} =0.
$$
Integrating on $(0,T)$ leads to
\begin{equation}
\frac12m|\dot{\underline{r}}(T)|^2+\int_0^Tk|\dot{\underline{r}}(t)|^2 \,dt=E_0,
\end{equation}
where $E_0=\frac12 m |\dot{\underline{r}}(0)|^2$. Since $E_0$ is bounded and the two terms on the left-hand side are positive, we also have that
$$
\int_0^Tk|\dot{\underline{r}}(t)|^2 \,dt
$$
is bounded, for all $T>0$. Therefore, as $T\to\infty$, we necessarily get $|\dot{\underline{r}}(T)|^2\to 0$, thus $|\dot{\underline{r}}(T)|\to 0$. But, if this is the case, then the kinetic energy term,
$$
\frac12m|\dot{\underline{r}}(T)|^2
$$
also tends to $0$ and thus we have energy dissipation. Hence, $\underline{F}$ is not conservative.

Is this correct?

**Note:** At the moment, my students haven't learned the concept of work, so I specifically want to find an alternative proof.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104098/discussion-on-question-by-sam-wolfe-a-proof-that-air-resistance-isnt-conservati).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I will start first  with spring mass system to show that the energy is conserved .

**System I**

The equation of motion

$$m\ddot{r}+c\,r=0$$

multiple by $\dot{r}$

$$m\dot{r}\ddot{r}+c\,\dot{r}\,r=0$$

or
$$m\,\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\left(\dot{r}^2\right)+c\,\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\left({r}^2\right)=0$$

thus

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(T+U\right)=0\quad,\Rightarrow\quad T+U=\text{const.=E}$$

where 
$T=\frac{m}{2}\dot{r}^2\quad,$ the kinetic energy and 
$U=\frac{c}{2}{r}^2$ the potential energy.

thus the energy $E$ is conserved.

**System II**

we have now parallel to the spring a damper element where the force of the damper is proportional to the
velocity

The equation of motion

$$m\ddot{r}+c\,r+k\,\dot{r}=0$$

again multiple by $\dot{r}$ you get

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(T+U\right)+k\,\dot{r}^2=0$$

$\Rightarrow$

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(E\right)=-k\,\dot{r}^2$$

or
$$E=-k\,\int \dot{r}^2\,dt=f(t)+ \text{const.}$$

thus the energy $E=E(t)$  is not a conserved !

**edit:**

better way to show the energy conservation is to transfer the equation to first order differential equation.

**System I**

$$m\ddot{r}+c\,r=0$$

first order ODE's

$$\dot{r}=z$$

$$\dot{z}=-\bar{c}\,r\quad, \bar{c}=\frac{c}{m}$$

with the energy :

$$E=\frac{z^2}{2}+\int \bar{c}\,r\,dr=T+U $$

$$\frac{dE}{dt}=\frac{\partial E}{\partial z}\dot{z}+\frac{\partial E}{\partial r}\dot{r}=z\,(-\bar{c}\,r)+\bar{c}\,r\,z=0$$

thus the energy is conserve

**System II**

$$m\ddot{r}+c\,r+k\,\dot{r}=0$$

first order ODE's

$$\dot{r}=z$$

$$\dot{z}=-\bar{c}\,r-\bar{k}\,z$$

Energy

$$E=\frac{z^2}{2}+\int \bar{c}\,r\,dr+\int \bar{k}\,z\,dz$$

$$\frac{dE}{dt}=(z+\bar{k}\,z)\,(-\bar{c}\,r-\bar{k}\,z)+\bar{c}\,r\,z\ne 0$$

thus the energy is not conserve

Comment: Thank you, but unless I'm missing something, that doesn't answer my question. Could you please explain further and in the case of only considering air resistance?

Comment: I guess in my case, since I don't have potential energy ($U=0$), I could simply say $E=T=-\int_0^T k \dot{\underline{r}}(t) \,dt=f(t)+\text{const}$, right?

Comment: Furthermore, when going from $\frac{d}{dt}(T+U)=0$ to $T+U=\text{const}$, maybe you should write $\frac{d}{dt}(T(t)+U(t))=0$ to $T(T)+U(T)=T(0)+U(0)$, no?

Comment: Also, why do you define potential energy as $U=\frac{c}{2}r^2$? How does it relate with the usual definition $U=-\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\underline{F}\cdot \underline{dx}$?.

Comment: If $F=c\,x$ you get from your integral the Potential energy?, yes T and U are function of the time t. We are using T different. I use T for kinetic energy. The air resistance has the same force as my Dampfer force

Comment: Yes, and how do I get the potential energy in my case? Is it really zero?

Comment: $E=-\int_0^T\dot{r}^2\,dt=-f(T)+f(0)$

Comment: Why is that the potential energy?

Comment: If you have time, please take a look at my solution (posted as an answer).

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found a possible solution to this problem. I'll post it as an answer as it's a bit extensive.

I think my original proof simply shows that kinetic energy is dissipated under such force and through the integral term. Further machinery might be needed to show that $\underline{F}$ is non-conservative. My main suspicion, as discussed in the comment section, is that nothing conclusive can be said about potential energy with such approach.

First, note that non-conservative forces do not mean energy is not conserved. The law of total energy conservation is always valid, but non-conservative forces convert some of the mechanical energy into other energy forms, such as heat. One can indeed say that mechanical energy is not conserved, but not total energy.

In fact, $\underline{F}$ is a non-conservative force, but to prove this one would need to show that work is path dependent. Furthermore, being only dependent on position is a necessary condition for a force to be conservative. If the force has explicit time (or velocity) dependence, we are not able to define a potential energy $U(\underline{r})$ associated with it that depends only on position.

On the other hand, if the potential energy depends on time (or velocity), mechanical energy is not conserved. Let's do the time case, for example, $U\equiv U(\underline{r},t)$ (the velocity case is similar). Then,
$$
\frac{dU}{dt}=\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial U}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{\partial U}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}+\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}=\nabla U\cdot \dot{\underline{r}}+\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}.
$$
We also have that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac12 m |\dot{\underline{r}}(t)|^2  \right)=\underline{F}\cdot \dot{\underline{r}}=-\nabla U \cdot \dot{\underline{r}} =\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}-\frac{dU}{dt}\Leftrightarrow \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac12 m |\dot{\underline{r}}(t)|^2 +U \right)=\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}\neq 0.
$$
Hence, mechanical energy is only conserved if $U$ is independent of $t$. In the case $U\equiv U(\underline{r},\dot{\underline{r}},t)$, we get
$$
\frac{d}{dt}E_{\text{mec}}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac12 m |\dot{\underline{r}}(t)|^2 +U \right)=\nabla_{\dot{\underline{r}}}U\cdot \ddot{\underline{r}}+\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}\neq 0,
$$
where $\nabla_{\dot{\underline{r}}}U\equiv \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial \dot{x}},\frac{\partial U}{\partial \dot{y}},\frac{\partial U}{\partial \dot{z}}\right)$.

This solution seems quite general (note that I haven't even used the expression of $\underline{F}$). Any ideas/comments?